# Next JS meta tags not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

When the page initially loads it renders the correct site title as meta tag for 1/2 a second then replaces it with the current URL as title in the browser. View page source shows the correct meta tags with data but it has not rendered within the DOM in the head tags. This is true for both dev and production environments.

I'm using getStaticProps which should be pre fetching data

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<
  PageProps,
  Query,
  PreviewData
> = async (ctx) => {
  const { preview = false, previewData = {} } = ctx

  const token = previewData.token
  const [settings, page = fallbackPage] = await Promise.all([
    getSettings({ token }),
    getHomePage({ token }),
  ])

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      settings,
      preview,
      token: previewData.token ?? null,
    },
  }
}


export async function getHomePage({
  token,
}: {
  token?: string
}): Promise<HomePagePayload | undefined> {
  return await sanityClient(token)?.fetch(homePageQuery)
}


export const homePageQuery = groq`
  *[_type == "home"][0]{
    _id,
    title,
    overview,
  }
`
```

Meta tags component

```
<Head>
  <HomePageHead page={page} settings={settings} />
</Head>


export interface HomePageHeadProps {
  settings?: SettingsPayload
  page?: HomePagePayload
}

export default function HomePageHead({ settings, page }: HomePageHeadProps) {
  return (
    <SiteMeta
      description={page?.overview ? toPlainText(page.overview) : ''}
      image={settings?.ogImage}
      title={page?.title}
    />
  )
}
```